# Object of class App\Profile could not be converted to int error

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to fetch data from two tables, whose 'id' in users table is a foreign key in the profile table as 'user_id'.

when the users register, I have also updated the profile table with the user.id as profile.user_id(the foreign key I told earlier).

This is the error I am getting:

> (2/2) ErrorException Object of class App\Profile could not be
>   converted to int (View:
>   C:\wamp64\www\AlumniTrack\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php)

//index.blade.php code

```
@if($users >0)
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {!!Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@destroy',$user->id],'method'=>'POST'])!!}
            <h3>{{$user->name}}</h3>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Student Number</label><br>
                            <label>Email</label><br>
                            <label>CID Number</label>
                            <label>Date of Birth</label>
                            <label>Mobile Number</label>
                            <label>Joining Year</label>
                            <label>Graduation Year</label>
                            <label>Program</label><br>
                            <label>Experience</label>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <h5>{{$user->student_no}}</h5>
                        <h5>{{$user->email}}</h5>    
                        <h5>{{$user->profile->CID}}</h5>    
                </div> 

        @endforeach
    @endif
```

//index function in ProfileController

```
public function index()
    {
        $id=Auth::User()->id;
        $user=User::find($id);
        return view('profile.index')->with('users',$user->profile);   
    }
//profile model
public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
//user model
public function profile(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
    }
```

in the profile page. I expect to fetch all the data from both the tables so users can update themselves. I have used this in a similar project and was working fine. I don't know where I went wrong here.

Comment: what are you trying to do with your `index` method? fetching all profiles of user or fetching all users? I see you are fetching the current user only and passing his profile to the view?!

Comment: I am trying to fetch all profiles of a user. I have a relationship made in their models but i am not able to access details from the profile table. I will edit my question and include the relationships too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to compare a collection with number,

```
//update your code here
@if(count($users) > 0)
    @foreach($users as $user)
        {!!Form::open(['action'=>['PostsController@destroy',$user->id],'method'=>'POST'])!!}
            <h3>{{$user->name}}</h3>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <label>Student Number</label><br>
                            <label>Email</label><br>
                            <label>CID Number</label>
                            <label>Date of Birth</label>
                            <label>Mobile Number</label>
                            <label>Joining Year</label>
                            <label>Graduation Year</label>
                            <label>Program</label><br>
                            <label>Experience</label>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                        <h5>{{$user->student_no}}</h5>
                        <h5>{{$user->email}}</h5>    
                        <h5>{{$user->profile->CID}}</h5>    
                </div> 

        @endforeach
    @endif
```

Comment: pls edit post only what change. Find diff is boring.

Comment: Thanks. This problem just got resolved but another one just came. "Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\AlumniTrack\resources\views\profile\index.blade.php)" . Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @daremachine, comment added where code should be change.

Comment: @tencho, Just do dd($users) inside your index method and get idea what your collection contains.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli better update your question if any update than write answer in comments :D